# Как подгрузить данные из redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Есть такой массив в reducer

```
const initialState = {
  0: [
    {
      comment: '1 сезон',
      folder: [
        {
          comment: '1 серия'
        },
        {
          comment: '2 серия'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      comment: '2 сезон',
      folder: [
        {
          comment: '1 серия'
        },
        {
          comment: '2 серия'
        },
        {
          comment: '3 серия'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Хочу использовать так:

```
const View = () => {
  return (
    <div className="content">
      <ItemList items={obj[0]} /> // Тут я хочу выгрузить все comment
      <div className="video"></div>
      <ItemList items={obj[0][1]['folder']} /> // тут я хочу выгрузить все folder по тому, какой у меня стоит comment
    </div>
  );
};
```

См ItemList:

```
const ItemList = ({ items }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <ul className="items">
      {items.map(({ comment }, index) => (
        <li
          key={index}
          className={active === index ? 'item active' : 'item'}
          onClick={() => setActive(index !== active ? index : -1)}
        >
          {comment}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Обьект меня не нужно, он должен быть таким.

> Для тех кто не понял: есть сериал и мы можем выбрать сезон и появяться
> у нас все серии к этому сезону

Comment: Не очень понятно, при чем тут redux. Так же придется состояние вынести на компонент выше

Comment: Ну в redux будет лежать данные

Comment: То есть, данные будут отправляться в redux и из redux их доставать. Хочу сделать чтобы по клику на сезон подгружались все его серии